# Python ldap3 connect to windows ldap badPwdCount return back to 0 always after conn.search

Tags: python, windows, ldap

User entered wrong password and I see that the badPwdCount in ldap increment to 1 or 2.

[image]

However, after I run the below python script to query the user attribute, the badPwdCount return to 0. Any clue?

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection
from pprint import pprint

server_uri = 'ldaps://193.178.115.11'
userid = 'user1'
password = 'user1password'
base = 'OU=Champ,DC=soobdev,DC=hq'
user_base = 'CN=%s,%s' % (userid, base)
search_filter = '(CN=%s)' % userid
attrs = ['*']

server = Server(server_uri, get_info='ALL')
with Connection(server, user=user_base, password=password, auto_bind=True ) as conn:
    pprint('conn.result %s' % conn.result)
    conn.search(base, search_filter, attributes=attrs)
    pprint('conn.entries %s' % conn.entries)
```

Comment: Did you execute the search *as that user?* That would mean that you also did a successful bind as that user, which resets the bad password count. You need do the search as an admin user.

Comment: admin user of ldap? or admin user of windows? but why just a search can change the badPwdCount back to 0?

Comment: (1) Admin user of LDAP, i.e. not the user concerned. (2) For the reason I already stated, if you did the search as the user concerned.

Comment: setting auto_bind=False solve this problem :)